# AD Account are being locked but only some are showing as 4740 in Domain controller

Tags: security, user-accounts, windows-server-2008, active-directory, event-viewer

**We have been seeing increasing number of AD Account lockouts.**

Some of these lockouts show up in event viewer as 4740 events but most do not show up at all.  My account has been locked out almost once a day, there is never a 4740 event associated with it.  However, if I try to login in with a bad password *eg:BadPwd123* till my account is locked out, I see the 4740 in eventviewer.

Are there other event lockouts other than 4740 That I can be searching for?

**I have already enabled**

```
Computer Configuration -> Windows Settings -> Security Settings -> Advanced Audit Policy Configuration -> Audit Policies->
```

[image]

Comment: A common cause is that the user may be logged in on multiple computers or disconnected remote terminal server sessions.  People disconnected are not necessarily logged out. Remote work at this time may exacerbate this issue.

Comment: I am asking about Active Directory Accounts being locked @John
I am asking for Event ID's to search though eventviewer logs.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  The above came up with that error code and because people can have too many sessions running.

Comment: How do you know the account is locked? Is your security log large enough to hold all the events or are they being overwritten? Also the event only occurs on the domain controller that locks the account.